# android how many services can I have?

Tags: android, service, notifications, tooltip

how many Android services can I have in an android application?

This is more so curiosity but the answers can influence my future coding decisions. Although I skimmed the services page in the android documentation, I pretty much shun that site because I always have to google "android [topic] example" or tutorial.

How many services can I have before things get really wonky? Or people start hating on the app because of battery life concerns or other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't the number of services but what they do and how long they live. Most applications can get away with one service, perhaps two. More than that, and I'd consider it a bit of a code smell.

User concerns will tend to arise from services that are running when there's no obvious reason for them to be running.